# how to get the id of repeater item into a jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I get the `id` of a textbox within the nested repeater using jQuery?

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = jQuery.noConflict();
    e(document).ready(function () {
        e("#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>, #datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpfollowup">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpactivity" OnItemDataBound="rpactivity_ItemDataBound" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="Activities" runat="server" CssClass="span10"   Text='<%#Eval("Activity")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="span10" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%#Eval("Start_Date")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have reduced the code to avoid confusion.

<%= datepicker.ClientID %> gives red underline as it cannot detect the ID within the repeaters.
Kindly give a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the HTML that this control renders to the question.

Comment: It would be easier if you add class "datepicker" to the control instead of using the ID.  `CssClass="span10 datepicker"`

Comment: Ok. After adding the class, what changes should i make to the jquery?? (i am weak with jquery!!)

Comment: `e(".datepicker").datepicker({ ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's ASP.NET `repeater` control, all the controls will repeat itself and so the textboxes, so you will have `Ids` appended with 1,2,,and so on. Thus, use class in your textbox instead and apply function like this:-

```
e(".datepicker").datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true
});
```

**Update:-**
Use this for repeater, since there will be multiple textboxes for each item.

```
$('.datepicker').each(function () {
      $(this).datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true});
});
```

Where i have added the class in your mark-up like this:-

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="span10 datepicker" 
  ClientIDMode ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%#Eval("Start_Date")%>'></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Also, Please note since this is Repeater, controls will repeat so you need to reference the current elements in the current context using `$(this)`

Comment: Thanks Rahul,

But still, when i add calendar date to the textbox of 2nd item of the repeater, the value sits on the textbox of the first item.

Comment: @DivyaMenezes - Thats what I mentioned in my last para, you need to fetch the context using `$(this)` otherwise it will always pick the first element.

Comment: Really Sorry, i haven't got it yet. the calendar stops appearing once i add 'this'. Could you please give a complete idea of code?